# Need help with Doctrine 2 Relations (inversedBy)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

```
class Affiliate
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", length=4)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Entities\AdminUser $admin_user
     *
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="AdminUser", inversedBy="affiliate")
     */
    private $admin_user;    
}


class AdminUser
{

    /**
    * @var integer $id
    *
    * @Column(name="id", type="integer", length=4)
    * @Id
    * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    */
    private $id;

   /**
   * @var Entities\Affiliate $affiliate
   *
   * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Affiliate", mappedBy="admin_user", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
   */
   private $affiliate;
}



$admin_user4 = new Entities\AdminUser();

$affiliate = new Entities\Affiliate();
$admin_user4->setAffiliate($affiliate);

$this->em->persist($admin_user4);
```

...

```
mysql> select * from affiliate;
+----+---------------+
| id | admin_user_id |
+----+---------------+
|  1 |          NULL |
+----+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

WHY IS THIS NULL??????

Comment: Sorry this formatting of that mysql query is unreadble

Comment: Also, I'm flushing the entityManager via a Zend Application Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

What does setAffiliate() look like?

Since it's the inverse side of the association, it should look something like this:

```
public function setAffiliate($affiliate){
    $affiliate->admin = $this;
    $this->affiliate = $affiliate;
    return $this;
}
```

Your cascade annotations are ineffective because you've made Affiliate the owning side.

So another solution, which may or may not make more sense, would be to flip the ownership on the association.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like:

```
$admin_user4 = new Entities\AdminUser();

$affiliate = new Entities\Affiliate();
$admin_user4->setAffiliate($affiliate);

$this->em->persist($admin_user4);

$this->em->flush();
```